# Finding the arc length of $r(t)=ti+j+(\frac{1}{6}t^3+\frac{1}{2}t^{-1})$

Tags: calculus, plane-curves

How would I find the arc length of the following curve from $t=0$ to $t=2$

$r(t)=ti+j+(\frac{1}{6}t^3+\frac{1}{2}t^{-1})$

I took the first derivative and got

$r(t)'=(1+\frac{1}{2}t^2-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{t^2})$

then I factored it out a $\frac{1}{2}$

and got  $\frac{1}{2}(t^2-\frac{1}{t^2}+2)$
I then squared it and got $\frac{1}{4}(t^4-\frac{1}{t^4}+2)$

I then took the square root and integral but I find myself stuck. On solving the integral.

$\int_0^2\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}(t^4-\frac{1}{t^4}+2)}$

Comment: Your squared expression is completely wrong: $$\left(t^2-\frac1{t^2}+2\right)^2=t^4-2t^2\left(\frac1{t^2}-2\right)+\left(2- \frac{1}{t^2}\right)^2=t^4-2+4t^2+4-\frac4{t^2}+\frac1{t^4}$$

Comment: for the curve shouldn't be $r(t)=ti+j+(\frac{1}{6}t^3+\frac{1}{2}t^{-1})k$ ?

Comment: I see so I placed the $\sqrt{t^4-2+4t^2+4-\frac{4}{t^2}+\frac{1}{t^4}}$

Comment: and then hmm now the question is how to take the integral...

Comment: Ok, let's pay some attention here, @Fernando: $$\sqrt{\left(t^2-\frac1{t^2}+2\right)^2}=t^2+2-\frac1{t^2}\;\ldots !$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\vec{\rm r}\pars{t} = t\,{\bf i} + {\bf j}
     + \pars{{1 \over 6}\,t^{3} + \half\,t^{-1}}{\bf k}}$

> \begin{align}
> {\cal L}&\equiv\int_{t = 0}^{t = 2}\verts{\dd\vec{\rm r}\pars{t}}
> =\int_{0}^{2}\verts{\totald{\vec{\rm r}\pars{t}}{t}}\,\dd t
> =\int_{0}^{2}
> \root{1^{2} + 0^{2} + \bracks{{1 \over 6}\,3t^{2} + \half\pars{-t^{-2}}}^{2}}\,\dd t
> \\[3mm]&=\int_{0}^{2}
> \root{1 + {1 \over 4}\,t^{4} - \half + {1 \over 4t^{4}}}\,\dd t
> =\half\int_{0}^{2}{\root{t^{8} + 2t^{4} + 1} \over t^{2}}\,\dd t
> =\half\int_{0}^{2}{t^{4} + 1 \over t^{2}}\,\dd t
> \end{align}
>   $\large\tt\mbox{The integral diverges !!!}$.

Comment: I see so it diverges

Answer (score 1):

You need to find $\vert r'\left(t\right)\vert$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** Given a vector $r(t) = <f(t)$, $g(t)$, $h(t)>$. The arc length is $$L = \int_a^b\sqrt{(f'(t))^2 + (g'(t))^2 + (h'(t))^2}dt$$
The components have to be squared seperately.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is $r(t)'=(1+\frac{1}{2}t^2-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{t^2})$ should be $r(t)'=(1,0,\frac{1}{2}t^2-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{t^2})$ and so $|r'(t)|=\sqrt{r'.r'}$